# SQL Server truncation configuration

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2008 R2 a temp-table in a stored procedure is defined with 2 varchar fields of length 25 and 50 that are too short for some of the data that is inserted into them.  So this error makes perfect sense:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure XYZ, Line 48 
>   String or binary data would be truncated. 
>   The statement has been terminated.

The trouble is, this error has only just started occurring in our production environment, and this is causing problems.  Our UAT environment has lots of data that could also trigger this error, but doesn't.

We could just lengthen the fields in the stored procedure, but we would like to understand what change or setting could have caused this error to start appearing in production.  We checked ANSI_WARNINGS and they were FALSE in both environments.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess I'm just a bit confused.  You state, "..2 varchar fields of length 25 and 50 that are too short for some of the data that is inserted into them...".  You're basically specifically stating exactly why this error occurs.  It's not a setting or a change, you're trying to put data into a place where it won't fit.

Comment: He says, it only happens on Production and UAT database has no problem but it should.

Comment: So basically, "We work with data that can be larger than our set column length.  Box A should have problems but somehow magically works.  Box B used to magically work, doesn't work anymore.  Please tell me why this is happening."  I mean I understand you're potentially working with sensitive materials but you need to provide more information.

Comment: @SourceSimian, you'd better to post on DBA site: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: It might be `ANSI_WARNINGS` is `ON` for a particular connection or turn on in the client at some time during the execution. Use `SQL Profiler` to verify

Comment: @Squirrel It did indeed turn out to be something connection-related

Comment: Glad you found the cause :)